# How do I Feed local Data (Images) into my Keras Network in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feed

I am using the newest version of Tensorflow and Keras. 
I have seen the example where datasets like the MNIST ist loaded and used.

But how do I do this with local images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `ImageDataGenerator`, which shuffles your data and can do augmentation for you (see https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/ ).

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'your_training_images/train',
    target_size=(image_height, image_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading all your local images:

```
import cv2
import os,sys
from glob import glob

folder = "path_to_images_folder"
images = glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.images_extension/s'))
```

Then you can convert the images into an array of determined width & height pixels:

```
def proc_images():
"""
Returns  array x of resized images: 
"""
    x = []
    WIDTH = 32 #you can adapt to the desired_width(i.e. 64, 128)
    HEIGHT = 32 #you can adapt to the desired_height ( 64, 128)

    for img in images:
        base = os.path.basename(img)


    # Read and resize image
        full_size_image = cv2.imread(img)
    #x.append(full_size_image)
        x.append(cv2.resize(full_size_image, (WIDTH,HEIGHT), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))

    return x

x = proc_images()
```

from this point you can join the images associated labels and start developing the desired neural network by using the input_shape(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3).

Example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
```